# JSON encode, parsing and calling confusion

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

So my server send a json encoded array to client.
Client use JSON.parse on it, but when Im trying to extract the data Im getting a error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined`, but Im sure description is one of the key because running:

Does it have something to do with reactjs? My code:

```
<script type="text/jsx">
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var HabitModel = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function(){
    return {
    data: [],
    pageAmount: 0
  };
},

componentDidMount: function(){
    this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, {userid:123},      function(result){
    result = JSON.parse(result);
    this.setState({
      data: result,
      pageAmount: Math.ceil(result.length/4)
    });

  }.bind(this));
},

render: function() {
  return (
    <div>
      the habit is:
      <HabitList data={this.state.data} />
    </div>
  );
}
})

    var HabitList = React.createClass(
  {
    render: function(){
  return(
  { //error line here
    JSON.stringify(this.props.data[0].description)
   }
      )

}

  });

    React.render(
  <HabitModel source = "/health1/server/habit/user"/>,
  document.getElementById('myDiv')
    );
    </script>
```

The error is in the line `JSON.stringify(this.props.data[0].description)`
it works perfect if I put `this.props.data[0]`, and it will output a JSON as follows:

`{"habitid":"1","userid":"123","description":"go to the gym","startDate":"0000-00-00","goalDate":"0000-00-00"}`

As you can see one of the key is description. So how come `this.props.data[0].description` is not working?

---

edit:
I found out that if I were to do a console.log right after ajax call

```
componentDidMount: function(){
this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, {userid:123},      function(result){
result = JSON.parse(result);

console.log(result[0].description); //ADDED LINE, this would work

this.setState({
  data: result,
  pageAmount: Math.ceil(result.length/4)
});

  }.bind(this));
},
```

This will recognize that description is one of the key. What is going on with reactjs?

Comment: this.props or this.props.description[0] doesn't seems to have a description property. Use console.log to debug correctly ...

Comment: What is the actual shape of `this.props.description`? This error means that `this.props.description[0]` is `undefined`.

Comment: this.props.description[0] is fine because I was able to read from it with the JSON.stringify, as you can see in the post. The actual shape of this.props.description is [{"habitid":"1","userid":"123","description":"go to the gym","startDate":"0000-00-00","goalDate":"0000-00-00"},{"habitid":"2","userid":"123","description":"study hard","startDate":"0000-00-00","goalDate":"0000-00-00"},{"habitid":"3","userid":"123","description":"go to the park","startDate":"0000-00-00","goalDate":"0000-00-00"} [...] ]

Comment: I can see why the confusion though, it is my variable naming. Ill change the variable to make it more understandable

Comment: @carlosDelgado, it does have the description property though, that's why I showed in the post what get output when I do `console.log JSON.stringify(this.props.data[0])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the problem.
It become clear when you realize componentDidMount doesnt get run until the initial rendering occur. So at the beginning it passed a empty data to the child. That's why I couldnt get the Description out of data despite there is a description key in the JSON

Answer (score 0):

there is not enough code here to see what is going on why the `description[0]` value is `undefined` and doesn't have a `description` property.

Are you setting the property when you create the `HabitList`?

```
<HabitList description=[{description: "Aaa"}]/>
```

try to run the code like this to see what is going on

```
var HabitList = React.createClass(
  {
    render: function () {
      return (
      <ul>
        {JSON.stringify(this.props.description)}
      </ul>
      )
    }
  })
```

Comment: I have tried running that code already and it just give me the following:  [{"habitid":"1","userid":"123","description":"go to the gym","startDate":"0000-00-00","goalDate":"0000-00-00"},{"habitid":"2","userid":"‌​123","description":"study hard","startDate":"0000-00-00","goalDate":"0000-00-00"},{"habitid":"3","userid":‌​"123","description":"go to the park","startDate":"0000-00-00","goalDate":"0000-00-00"} [...] ]

Comment: hmm, strange, your code should work then... Can you paste the full error, if there is more, like a stack trace.

Comment: ok I will paste it on the original post, along with the full code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In JS you can access JSON properties of a parsed JSON string using square brackets `[]`.

So for example:
If you have parsed your json in `var1` and you want to get the "property" key from the json, you should use `var1["property"]`. Assuming of course that the "property" key is first-level!

Comment: yea Im aware of that, and have tried it JSON.stringify(this.props.description[0]["description"]), but Im still getting the same error